# Trying to upload a zip file to nexus using power shell, but it fails

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, invoke-command

I am very new to power shell scripting, have issue while uploading zip file to nexus, below is the power shell script that i have used for uploading

```
$FilePath = "C:\Users\asd\SomeFile.zip";
$Uri = 'https://some.place.over.the.rainbow.com/api/v1/dataupdate';
$user = 'user_name'
$pass = 'abc123'
$pair = "$($user):$($pass)"
$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"

$Headers = @{
    Authorization = $basicAuthValue
};

$fileBin = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($FilePath)
$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")
$fileEnc = $enc.GetString($fileBin)
$boundary = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()   
$LF = "`r`n"; # and tried with $LF = "`n";
$bodyLines = (
        "--$boundary",
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"file`"$LF",   
        $fileEnc,
        "--$boundary--$LF"
        ) -join $LF

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method Post -ContentType "multipart/form-data; boundary=`"$boundary`"" -Headers $Headers -Body $bodyLines
```

it fails with the below error

`cannot send content-body with this verb-type`

i am using powershell version 5.x

Comment: did you miss h in http?  `$Uri = 'ttps://some.place.over.the.rainbow.com/api/v1/dataupdate';`

Comment: no uri is proper, sorry may be while copy pasting  is missed it. i have edited the question

Comment: what is the version of nexus?? if Nexus2 then try this https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465818-How-can-I-programmatically-upload-an-artifact-into-Nexus-2-?page=2